# Row increment in paste reference

Tags: vba, excel

As below code, the input fields are B3, C18, C20, C22, C24. (Fixed input fields)
These data going to paste starting from B41:F41.

Problem is, how do I make the increment of the output reference B41:F41 as row +1 each time the macro is being used? Consider as, if there are data in B41:F41, then the paste range would be B42:F42 and so on.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
```

`Range("B3").Copy Range("C41")`

```
Range("C18").Copy Range("B41")
Range("C20").Copy Range("D41")
Range("C22").Copy Range("E41")
Range("C24").Copy Range("F41")
```

Comment: can you paste it to the next empty row ? or it doesn't have to be so ?

Comment: Will there always be data in ColB, or could some copied cells be empty?

Answer (score 1):

If there will be no empty values copied to ColB then:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim sht As WorkSheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    With sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        sht.Range("B3").Copy .Cells(3)
        sht.Range("C18").Copy .Cells(2)
        sht.Range("C20").Copy .Cells(4)
        sht.Range("C22").Copy .Cells(5)
        sht.Range("C24").Copy .Cells(6)
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transfering your data to an array first, then transfering this array to the required section of the worksheet.

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Macro()

    Dim CopyRange As Range, c As Range
    Dim HoldArray() As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Define Non-Contiguous range
        Set CopyRange = Range("B3, C18, C20, C22, C24")

        'Count of cells in range
        n = CopyRange.Cells.Count

        'Resize the array to hold the data
        ReDim HoldArray(1 To n)

        n = 1

        'Store the values from that range into array
        For Each c In CopyRange.Cells

            HoldArray(n) = c.Value
            n = n + 1

        Next c

    End With

    'Paste array as contiguous range

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B41") = "" Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B41").Resize(1, UBound(HoldArray)).Value = HoldArray

    Else

        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, UBound(HoldArray)).Value = HoldArray

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could

- gather input values in an array
- write them in one shot

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    With Worksheets("SheetName") '<--| change "SheetName" to your actual sheet name
        .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Max(41, .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row), 2).Resize(, 5) = GetValues(.Range("C18,B3,C20,C22,C24")) '<--| list input cells addresses in wanted output order
    End With

    ... other code

End Sub

Function GetValues(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iCell As Long

    ReDim vals(1 To rng.COUNT) As Variant
    For Each cell In rng
        iCell = iCell + 1
        vals(iCell) = cell.Value
    Next cell
    GetValues = vals
End Function
```